# Flash Rom and Recover Later

Tags: custom-roms, backup, rom, rom-flashing

I Want to put Android 2.3 on My Phone, its an ZTE Racer with Android 2.1 and the Manufacturer hasnt released the new version i have found a Rom, But im afraid to do it and lose my phone, can anybody tell me how to get my actual version of android back it up so if something goes wrong i can recover later? and how to put the new ROM on the Phone?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install a custom recovery, which can back up your original ROM so you can restore it later.  The Clockworkmod recovery is generally considered the best, [there's a build of it with instructions for the ZTE Racer at MoDaCo](http://android.modaco.com/content/zte-racer-roms-rom-customisation/331762/recovery-3-0-2-4-clockworkmod-recovery-for-zte-racer/).

Comment: And About flash the new rom in?

Comment: @Lordareon You should find a page with instructions for the particular ROM. If it doesn't have instructions with it, I wouldn't use it unless you can get some from people who have already tried it. Often, though, you name it "update.zip", put it on the root of your SD card, and use Clockwork Recovery to flash it (it has a nice menu option).

Comment: Clockworkmod does not seem to work with Samsung devices out of the box. I know there is a way around it but this requires flashing a different kernel which defeats the intended purpose of making a backup before mocking around with the device. Any solution for Samsung devices?

Comment: @user4188 It works with the Galaxy S just fine, what device do you have?  (Consider posting a separate question).